# Borrar los espacios de una frase e imprimirla después

Tags: c

Muy buenas, estoy intentando modificar una frase para imprimirla sin contar los espacios, es decir, por ejemplo introduzco: "Buenos días", el resultado deberá mostrar "Buenosdías".

Por el momento tengo hecho esto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MCHAR 99

int longitud_global_paraula (char paraula[]);
void imprimir_paraula_sense_espais (char paraula [], int res);

    void main () {

        char paraula [19];
        int res1;

            system ("clear");
            printf ("Introdueix una frase: ");
            scanf ("%[^\n]", paraula);
            getchar ();

            //Parte 1       
            printf ("Frase introduïda: %s\n", paraula);
            //Parte 2
            res1 = longitud_global_paraula (paraula);
            printf ("Longitud total de la frase: %d\n", res1);
            //Parte 3
            res2 = imprimir_paraula_sense_espais (paraula);
            printf ("Frase introduïda sense espais: %s\n", res2 );              

    }

    int longitud_global_paraula (char paraula[]) {
        int i;
        i = 0;
        while ((paraula [i] != '\0') && (i < MCHAR )) {
            i ++;
        }
        return (i);     
    }

    //Funcion 4
    void imprimir_paraula_sense_espais (char paraula [], int res){
        int i, j, ult_pos;
        ult_pos = longitud_global_paraula (paraula);

        for (i = ult_pos -1; i ++) {
            if (paraula [i]== ' ') {
                j = i;
                while (paraula [j] != '\0') {
                    paraula [j] = pararula [j + 1];
                    j ++;
                }
            }
            else {
                i ++;
            }
        }
        return (j + i);
    }
```

Todo esto hace referencia a la "Función 4" y a la "parte 3" del programa.

De antemano, gracias.

CÓDIGO ARREGLADO:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MCHAR 99

int longitud_global_paraula (char paraula[]);
void imprimir_paraula_sense_espais (char paraula []);

    void main () {

        char paraula [19];
        int res;

            system ("clear");
            printf ("Introdueix una frase: ");
            scanf ("%[^\n]", paraula);
            getchar ();

            //Printf - 1            
            printf ("Frase introduïda: %s\n", paraula);
            //Printf - 2
            res = longitud_global_paraula (paraula);
            printf ("Longitud total de la frase: %d\n", res);
            //Printf - 3
            imprimir_paraula_sense_espais (paraula);
            printf ("Frase introduïda sense espais: %s\n", paraula );           
            //Printf - 4




    }

    int longitud_global_paraula (char paraula[]) {
        int i;
        i = 0;
        while ((paraula [i] != '\0') && (i < MCHAR )) {
            i ++;
        }
        return (i);     
    }

    void imprimir_paraula_sense_espais (char paraula []){
        int i, j, ult_pos;
        ult_pos = longitud_global_paraula (paraula);
        for (i = 0; i < ult_pos; i ++) {
            if (paraula [i]== ' ') {
                j = i;
                while (paraula [j] != '\0') {
                    paraula [j] = paraula [j + 1];
                    j ++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes implementar esta funcion:

```
void fraseSinEspacios(char cadena[])
{
     int i=0,j;
     while(cadena){
            if(cadena==' ' && cadena[i+1]==' ')
                    for(j=i+1;cadena[j];j++)
                        cadena[j]=cadena[j+1];
            else { i++; }
     }
   return cadena;
}
```

y luego llamarla en:

```
 //Parte 3
        res2 = fraseSinEspacios(paraula);
        printf ("Frase introducida sin espacios: %s\n", res2 );
```

Comment: Al final ya logré solucionar la función. Actualizo el código solucionado a mi pregunta.
De todas formas, gracias.